# Cplex installation "Could not find a version that satisfies..." and "No matching distribution" for Apple M1

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, python-3.8, python-3.9, apple-m1

I am trying to run cplex on my M1. I am hoping I can get it to run on python 3.8/9 because I also need to run tensorflow (which I run through miniconda for M1). When I try to pip install it within the miniconda python environment, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cplex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cplex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry but there is currently no M1 port for CPLEX. Team is looking into it, but I cannot provide any ETA for now.

Best regards,

Comment: Viu-Long Kong, do you happen to have an update on when CPLEX will be providing an M1 port?

Comment: Done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892000/cplex-22-1-python-api-on-macbook-with-m1-architecture/74893489#74893489