# CPLEX 22.1 on MacBook with M1 architecture

Tags: python, macos, cplex

I do not succeed to install CPLEX (version 22.1.1) on a MacBook with M1 chip (macOS Ventura - 13.1).

The installer keeps installing the files for the wrong architecture, i.e., x86_64 instead of arm64.

```
/Applications/CPLEX_Studio2211/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx
```

When I try to use the Python API, I get an error containing the following message:

```
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

Using the C++ API, a similar error occurs:

```
building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

`uname -m` in the used terminal yields `arm64`

The installer is a Java-Application though. So I created a Java- Programm to see what architecture Java returns, and

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

returns `x86_64`.

So my guess is that this is the underlying issue.

Edit: I removed all java installations - just to make sure the installer can't use any existing installation, but the installer installs its own JRE anyways. I executed the installer again, and the  same issue occurs. What's strange is that I can actually solve a model in OPL without problems.

Seems like IBM has added support for the new architecture, but not tested it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CPLEX 22.1.1

> With respect to platforms, this release introduces support for Windows
> Server 2022 and MacOS Ventura. It also adds an ARM64 port for MacOS,
> allowing users to run CPLEX Optimization Studio natively on this
> architecture.

Comment: I was too fast. Still having the same problem.